# Insert security header in WCF

Tags: wcf, http, soap, wsse

I am making a WCF appliaction in C#. Its all new to me and I am not sure what I am looking for but I will try to explain it as best as I can. I am having a problem with inserting a security header in SOAP message. 
Here is my App.config file`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="FleetGrip" connectionString="data source=srv-gc-sqldev02.unitas.mobsat.local\sql2012dev2;initial catalog=FleetGrip;persist security info=True;user id=FleetGripUser;password=123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceBoxAdministrationImplServiceSoapBinding"
                         closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                         openTimeout="00:10:00"
                         receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                         sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                         allowCookies="false"
                         bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                         hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                         maxBufferSize="1048576000"
                         maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                         maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576000"
                         messageEncoding="Text"
                         textEncoding="utf-8"
                         transferMode="Buffered"
                         useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
                        maxStringContentLength="819200"
                        maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode ="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"
                       proxyCredentialType="None"
                       realm="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"
                     algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://bovbox-ipns.vas.vizada.com/WS_VBOX_BO/soap/serviceBoxAdministration"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceBoxAdministrationImplServiceSoapBinding"
        contract="BoxAdminServiceReference.ServiceBoxAdministrationImpl"
        name="ServiceBoxAdministrationImplPort" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And here is what I tried in code

```
namespace TesterTool.DataService
{    
    class ServiceLayerClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {    
        // ViewModel WCf    
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void CreateBox(string Username, string Password, string BoxID, string SoftwareId)
        {    
            var client = new BoxAdminServiceReference.ServiceBoxAdministrationImplClient();
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "adminvizada sas_dev2";
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "k2oURgx4PkXs";   

            using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
            {

                var h =
                    "<UsernameToken xmlns:wsu=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\"><Username>adminvizada sas_dev2</Username><Password Type=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText\">k2oURgx4PkXs</Password></UsernameToken>";
                var escaped = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(h);
                var header =
                    new MessageHeader<string>(h);
                var untypedHeader = header.GetUntypedHeader("Security",
                    System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"));
                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(untypedHeader/*new CustomMessageHeader()*/);
                var response = client.createBox("1215-100010", "4.0.2");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

Comment: And the error is... ?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header.

Comment: Add trace listener in order to receive more precise error information otherwise it is hard to come up with reason causing error.

Comment: The thing is that I am not inserting security header in a proper way. The whole security header is missing when I check it with fiddler.